# Show value in Tabulator progress bar

Tags: progress, tabulator

I want to show a number in the Tabulator progress bar. I am aware about the Tabulator option "tooltips", which shows tool tips on cells. However, I haven't succeeded yet to show the number in the Tabulator progress bar. So my question is: How could this be done?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: Are you talking about the Tabulator "Progress Bar" formatter?  http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/format, It looks like there is a "legend" option you could use for that.  If this isn't what you are referring to, we will need some more information about what exactly you are doing.  A jsfiddle example with working code is the best.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation. Yes I am talking about Tabulator "Progress Bar" formatter: tabulator.info/docs/4.6/format

The legend option is exactly what I am looking for, thanks!